# Web.py: How to send method info through web.py from

Tags: python, web.py

I need to send the value method info through web.py.
for example I have this method:

```
def printvalue(val1,val2):
    if val1>val2:
        print val1
    else:
        print val2

printvalue(4,5)
```

How can I send the `printvalue(4,5)` through web.py?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are asking for?

```
import web

urls = (
    '/(.*)', 'printvalue'
)
app = web.application(urls, globals())

class printvalue:        
    def GET(self, val1, val2):
        if val1>val2:
            return val1
        return return val2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

then just open your web browser and go to localhost:(the port you use)/?val1=100&val2=50